# Typescript Error with Module '"@azure/functions"' has no exported member 'app'

Tags: typescript, azure

Well, this is probably a typescript question but it is also related to Azure:

In my Azure function Nodejs code:

```
import {
  app,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponseInit,
  InvocationContext,
} from "@azure/functions";
import { workerExec } from "./worker";

export async function myappfunction1(
  request: HttpRequest,
  context: InvocationContext
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
  context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
  try {
    console.log(`Incoming event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    const result = await workerExec(event, context);
    console.log("Successfully processed event;");
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
}

app.http("myappfunction1", {
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: myappfunction1,
});
```

I get this error when building with the `tsc` command:

```
error TS2305: Module '"@azure/functions"' has no exported member 'app'.
error TS2724: '"@azure/functions"' has no exported member named 'HttpResponseInit'. 
error TS2305: Module '"@azure/functions"' has no exported member 'InvocationContext'
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "src/functions",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*"
  ]
}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Which version of `@azure/functions` are you using ?

Comment: `npm install @azure/functions@preview`

Comment: check with `npm ls @azure/functions` but you're likely relying on a v3 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by running:

```
npm install @azure/functions@preview
```

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced the issue at my environment and got expected result***

I have referred [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-typescript?pivots=nodejs-model-v4) to create a function in v4 model using typescript.

Initially when I created the function, I was getting the error too.

[image]

My folder structure was

[image]

Then I executed `npm run build` command. Upon successful execution, it created **`dist`** in my folder structure, where you can see your functions .js file has created. Because in my `tsconfig` file,  outDir is set to `"outDir" : "dist"`.

In your case, outDir is missing in your tsconfig file.

[image]

[image]

Then, it worked for me.

**`code:`**

```
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from  "@azure/functions";

export  async  function  myappfunction1(request:  HttpRequest, context:  InvocationContext):  Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
const  name  =  request.query.get('name') ||  await  request.text() ||  'world';
return { body:  `Hello, ${name}!` };
};

app.http('myappfunction1', {
methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
authLevel:  'anonymous',
handler:  myappfunction1
});
```

**`local.setting.json:`**

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
}
}
```

**`tsconfig.json:`**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es6",
"outDir": "dist",
"rootDir": ".",
"sourceMap": true,
"strict": false
}
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]